# Can't assign inline css to javascript elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a code that injects a div into a site. The problem is that I can't assign the css values via javascript, as they don't seem to take place on the document (not all of them).

Here is the code:

```
var barRoot = document.createElement('DIV'); 
barRoot.style.backgroundColor='#44AA44';
barRoot.style['height']='30px';
barRoot.style['width']='100%';
barRoot.style['position']='absolute';
barRoot.style['font-size']='14px';
barRoot.style['font-family']='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif';
barRoot.style['z-index']='99999001';
barRoot.style['font-weight']='bold';
barRoot.style['top']='0pt';
barRoot.style['left']='0pt';
barRoot.style['color']='White';
barRoot.style['padding']='0pt';
barRoot.style['margin']='0pt';
barRoot.style['border']='0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0)';
barRoot.id =  'irobRootElem1';  
document.body.insertBefore(barRoot, document.body.firstChild);  

var heartImg = document.createElement('IMG');   
heartImg.src = 'heart.png';  
heartImg.style['float']='left';  
heartImg.style['margin-left']='8px';  
heartImg.style['margin-top']='5px';  
heartImg.style['margin-right']='8px';  
barRoot.appendChild(heartImg);
```

Comment: What is your desired result? Right now the green background will not encapsulate the image, since the image is floated left and without height: http://jsfiddle.net/Tvm6A/

Comment: *"not all of them"*: Which ones? There is probably a reason for this.

Comment: Have you considered just adding a class to your inserted elements, and have the class declared in your stylesheet with all the wanted settings. Seems like the easy and efficient way to me...

Comment: thanks guys I did use classes afterwards but I just wanted to know why it didn't work it freaked me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to assign styles via JavaScript, the property names are not exactly the same as in your CSS file.

Check [this list in the w3c doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Style-20001113/css.html#CSS-CSS2Properties)

But as suggested, use of **classes** are **a lot more easier to use** than programmatically set styles.

Here is the list extracted from the w3 link above :

> ## Document Object Model (DOM) Level 2 Style Specification
>
> ### Version 1.0
>
> ### W3C Recommendation 13 November, 2000

```
azimuth
background
backgroundAttachment
backgroundColor
backgroundImage
backgroundPosition
backgroundRepeat
border
borderCollapse
borderColor
borderSpacing
borderStyle
borderTop
borderRight
borderBottom
borderLeft
borderTopColor
borderRightColor
borderBottomColor
borderLeftColor
borderTopStyle
borderRightStyle
borderBottomStyle
borderLeftStyle
borderTopWidth
borderRightWidth
borderBottomWidth
borderLeftWidth
borderWidth
bottom
captionSide
clear
clip
color
content
counterIncrement
counterReset
cue
cueAfter
cueBefore
cursor
direction
display
elevation
emptyCells
cssFloat
font
fontFamily
fontSize
fontSizeAdjust
fontStretch
fontStyle
fontVariant
fontWeight
height
left
letterSpacing
lineHeight
listStyle
listStyleImage
listStylePosition
listStyleType
margin
marginTop
marginRight
marginBottom
marginLeft
markerOffset
marks
maxHeight
maxWidth
minHeight
minWidth
orphans
outline
outlineColor
outlineStyle
outlineWidth
overflow
padding
paddingTop
paddingRight
paddingBottom
paddingLeft
page
pageBreakAfter
pageBreakBefore
pageBreakInside
pause
pauseAfter
pauseBefore
pitch
pitchRange
playDuring
position
quotes
richness
right
size
speak
speakHeader
speakNumeral
speakPunctuation
speechRate
stress
tableLayout
textAlign
textDecoration
textIndent
textShadow
textTransform
top
unicodeBidi
verticalAlign
visibility
voiceFamily
volume
whiteSpace
widows
width
wordSpacing
zIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a style tag instead. Use [setAttribute](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/setAttribute) to set inline style.